# JavaScript and knockoutjs strange behavior for this keyword

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have 3 partial knockoutjs binding in my pape

```
var model1= function()
        {
            self = this;
//somemethods here..
}
 var model2= function()
        {
            self = this;
 self.status = null;
            self.id = ko.observable(1);
             self.processingStatus = function ()
            {
                self.status = setInterval(function(){
                    var id = self.userId();//**self conteine link to model3**                                                                        
                }, 1100);
              }
            //somemethods here..

}

 var model3= function()
        {
            self = this;
//somemethods here..
}

  var m1 = new model1();                
ko.applyBindings(m1, document.getElementById("id1"));

        var m2 = new model2();
        ko.applyBindings(m2, document.getElementById("id2"));

        var m3= new modelHistory();
        ko.applyBindings(m3, document.getElementById("id3"));
```

inside of `processingStatus` method in model2, **self** pointer continent model3 data.
What does it happens and how to have different self pointer in each model class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the 'var' for self variables.

```
var self = this;
```